# API integration related problem in Stripe

Tags: java, stripe-payments

In Payment Intent API (https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object) ,
Many of the places it is written "RETRIEVABLE WITH PUBLISHABLE KEY" fo ex- id, currency, payment_method, what does it mean?

Whether it means that we can retrieve these value when we integrating the client SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The publishable key is used in your client-side code
[https://stripe.com/docs/keys#:~:text=On%20the%20client%2Dside.%20Can%20be%20publicly%2Daccessible%20in%20your%20web%20or%20mobile%20app%E2%80%99s%20client%2Dside%20code](https://stripe.com/docs/keys#:%7E:text=On%20the%20client%2Dside.%20Can%20be%20publicly%2Daccessible%20in%20your%20web%20or%20mobile%20app%E2%80%99s%20client%2Dside%20code)

So yes, when using Stripe SDK on your client-side using the publishable key (`pk_xxx`) you can retrieve only the fields that mention “retrievable with publishable key” in the doc.

If you use your secret key (`sk_xxx`) to retrieve a PaymentIntent, you will get access to all its properties.
Also, if you want to create a PaymentIntent you must use the secret key in your backend.